# Auth witnh angularfire2 difference between signInWithPopup and signInWithRedirect

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I want to add Google sing to my app and I use angularfire2.

To do it I use:

```
  oAuthLogin(provider) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(credential => {
      console.log(credential);
      Promise.resolve((this.user = credential));
    });
  }
```

And works OK in web but not in the APK.

I read is necessary to work in cordova to use `signInWithRedirect` because `signInWithPopup` is not compatible with it, but It not works.

I see the code of the pluging and is:

```
signInWithPopup(
      provider: firebase.auth.AuthProvider
    ): Promise<firebase.auth.UserCredential>;
    signInWithRedirect(provider: firebase.auth.AuthProvider): Promise<void>;
```

Then is normal doesn't work because `signInWithPopup` return a `UserCredential` and `signInWithRedirect` return void...

How can I adapt my code with fewer changes possible?

Comment: Check the documentation on this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova

Comment: Thanks bojeil.... I check in it and see what I say: signInWithPopup  it's not compatible with Cordova and have to use signInWithRedirect, but this break my app :-(